# Css and js files do not load into production

Tags: angular, deployment, build

When doing the deploy of my application on a tomcat8.5 server the imported css and js files are not loaded angular.json. locally works correctly

Comments:

This server has a link to external access when it is accessing an application for the server's IP or to a remote access server, but with the external access link the Css and js are not loaded.

I use the base href = "/ Project", not angular.json I define the paths as follows:

```
"node_modules / primeicons / primeicons.css",
"src / styles.css",
"node_modules / owl.carousel / dist / assets / owl.carousel.min.css",
"node_modules / owl.carousel / dist / assets / owl.theme.default.min.css",
"node_modules / bootstrap / dist / css / bootstrap.min.css",
"src / bootstrap3 / bootstrap3.min.css",
"node_modules / font-awesome / css / font-awesome.css",
"node_modules / primeng / resources / primeng.css",
"node_modules / primeng / resources / themes / nova-light / theme.css"
```

I've already tried:

do the project build with config --extract-css = false
and I've already changed this attribute to false in angular.json

Comments :

When you inspected a page it was possible that the file happens to be an error

```
Failed to load resource: net :: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

and this error indicates that it was in styles.e7efefb7ef5355459826.js: 1

I did a production build

Comment: are you sure that you did a production build?

Comment: Yes, i did a production build

Answer (score 0):

You should try `ng build --prod` in src folder?

Comment: I ran the build command inside the project root folder, not src, should I do this? What did you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Build with base href ng build --prod --base-href /Project/
Your index HTML is unable to find relative paths to your js bundles